# Crystal reports creating report from XML and exporting it to PDF without needing path to original XML

Tags: java, crystal-reports-xi

I have a Java web application that exports pdf files.

I have to use `Crystal Reports 11`. I can already export pdfs, the issue is that it only works locally because the `.rpt` file has a reference to an `XML` file in my machine.

So, when I want to export a report and the `.rpt` file can't find the file, even though I'm giving it a new dataset to work with it still throws a not found exception. I tried changing the file's connection programmatically but it always throws an exception related to the connection.

```
public InputStream export() throws ReportSDKException, IOException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
        reportClientDoc.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(localeTag));
        reportClientDoc.open(reportPath, OpenReportOptions._discardSavedData);
        DatabaseController databaseController = reportClientDoc.getDatabaseController();

        IConnectionInfo oldConn = databaseController.getConnectionInfos(null).get(0);
        IConnectionInfo newConn = resolveConnection(reportClientDoc).get(0);

        int replaceParams = DBOptions._ignoreCurrentTableQualifiers | DBOptions._doNotVerifyDB;
        databaseController.replaceConnection(oldConn, newConn, null,replaceParams);

        reportClientDoc.getDatabaseController().setDataSource(this.dataset);
        ParameterFieldController parameterController = reportClientDoc.getDataDefController()
                .getParameterFieldController();
        for (Param<Double> p : doubleParams) {
            parameterController.setCurrentValue(p.subReportName, p.fieldName, p.value);
        }

        for (Param<Object> p : objectParams) {
            parameterController.setCurrentValue(p.subReportName, p.fieldName, p.value);
        }

        return reportClientDoc.getPrintOutputController().export(this.format);
    }

private ConnectionInfos resolveConnection(ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc) throws ReportSDKException {
        IConnectionInfo oldConnection = new ConnectionInfo();
        DatabaseController dbController = reportClientDoc.getDatabaseController();
        oldConnection = dbController.getConnectionInfos(null).getConnectionInfo(0);

        String xsdPath = Paths.get(this.xsdPath).toAbsolutePath().toString();

        final String SERVER_NAME = dummyXmlPath + " " + xsdPath;
        final String DATABASE_DLL = oldConnection.getAttributes().getStringValue("Database DLL");
        final String LOCAL_SCHEMA_FILE = xsdPath;
        final String SERVER_TYPE = "XML";
        final String PREQESERVERNAME = SERVER_NAME;
        final String PREQESERVERTYPE = "XML";
        final String LOCAL_XML_FILE = dummyXmlPath;

        PropertyBag newAttributes = new PropertyBag();
        newAttributes.put("Server Name", SERVER_NAME);
        newAttributes.put("Database DLL", DATABASE_DLL);
        newAttributes.put("Local Schema File", LOCAL_SCHEMA_FILE);
        newAttributes.put("PreQEServerName", PREQESERVERNAME);
        newAttributes.put("PreQEServerType", PREQESERVERTYPE);
        newAttributes.put("Server Type", SERVER_TYPE);
        newAttributes.put("Local XML File", LOCAL_XML_FILE);

        IConnectionInfo newConnection = (IConnectionInfo) oldConnection.clone(true);
        newConnection.setAttributes(newAttributes);
        newConnection.setKind(oldConnection.getKind());

        ConnectionInfos connectionInfos = new ConnectionInfos();
        connectionInfos.add(newConnection);
        return connectionInfos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the Subreport data to the subreports.

```
SubreportController subreportController = reportClientDoc.getSubreportController();
for (String string : subreportController.querySubreportNames()) {
    subreportController.setDataSource(string, dataset);
}
```